# System.InvalidOperationException - CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've searched a lot but failed... I'm trying to create two tables, one having foreign key of another (specifically, *Url_Entries*'s url to be foreign key of *WordCount* class). But when I'm adding an object to the databse using code-first I'm getting exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233079
>     Message=The property 'url' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.
>     Source=EntityFramework
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionTypeConfiguration.NavigationProperty(PropertyPath propertyPath)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionTypeConfiguration.NavigationProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ForeignKeyPrimitivePropertyAttributeConvention.Apply(PropertyInfo memberInfo, ConventionTypeConfiguration configuration, ForeignKeyAttribute attribute)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PropertyAttributeConfigurationConvention`1.<.ctor>b__0(ConventionTypeConfiguration ec)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConvention.ApplyCore(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.TypeConventionBase.Apply(Type memberInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Convention.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyModelConfiguration(Type type, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
>          at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
>          at WebCrawler.save(Hashtable hashTable, String url) in c:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite7\App_Code\WebCrawler.cs:line 110
>          at WebCrawler.countAndSave(String content, String url) in c:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite7\App_Code\WebCrawler.cs:line 104
>          at index.Unnamed_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite7\index.aspx.cs:line 19
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     InnerException:

```
public class Url_Entries
{
    public Url_Entries(string url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
    }
    [Key]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int crawl_id { get; set; }
}



public class WordCount
{
    public WordCount(string url, string word, int count)
    {
      this.url = url;
      this.word = word;
      this.count = count;
    }
  public Url_Entries Url_Entries { get; set; }
  public string url { get; set; }
  [Required, ForeignKey("url")]
  public string word { get; set; }
  public int count { get; set; }

}




public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("ExploreCalifornia")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Url_Entries> Url_Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WordCount> WordCount { get; set; }
}





public class WebCrawler
{
    public static MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
    private static void save(Hashtable hashTable, string url)
    {
        Url_Entries newUrlEntry = new Url_Entries(url);
        db.Url_Entries.Add(newUrlEntry); //Exception on this line
    }
}
```

Exception in the last class. I've commented.

Comment: You're misusing `[ForeignKey]`

Comment: What to do? I want Url_Entries's url to be foreign key of WordCount.

Comment: The error message you posted appears to be incomplete; it ends in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `ForeignKey`-attribute on the wrong field. You want `url` to be the foreign key for `Url_Entries`, currently you are setting `word` to be the foreign key for `url`.

This section is wrong:

```
public Url_Entries Url_Entries { get; set; }
public string url { get; set; }
[Required, ForeignKey("url")]
public string word { get; set; }
```

Change to:

```
  [ForeignKey("url")]
  public Url_Entries Url_Entries { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string url { get; set; }
  public string word { get; set; }
```

To explain the error you are getting in greater detail: You are attempting to set a field of type `string` to be the foreign key of a field of type `string`. The error is telling you that the property which represents the other entity, referred to as *navigation property*, must be of "valid entity type". Valid entity type would a complex type which would represent the other table, therefore a `string` is not acceptable.

Comment: Now I get: System.Data.DataException

Comment: An exception occurred while initializing the database.

Comment: "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Comment: If the provider fails on Open then either your connection string is wrong, or your server is not accessible, which in turn may be due to numerous reasons. Make sure your connection string is correct.